# I'm trying to get a div inside another div to be on the bottom right

Tags: html, css

Been trying this for a little while but it all piles on top in the bottom right? This is as far as I've got. I want a margin around the links but I can't seem to have them spaced out? Any help would be appreciated,

```css
#banner {
 background-color: grey;
 color:white;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 
}
#link {
 padding: 0px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
  }
.selector{ background-color: white;
 color: grey;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="banner">
<div id="link"> <div class="selector">Home</div> </div>
<div id="link">About</div>
<div id="link">Projects</div>
<div id="link">About</div>
<div id="link">Contact</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might change the position:absolute, to relative in your #link class, also surround into another div with the right class as you might create like this:

```
.right{
  float:right;
}
```

I've made a Fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6amh52gs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use the same ID on five elements. IDs are only to be used once. If you want the same CSS for several elements, use a class, which I did below: I put the common properties into the class `link` which I assigned to all 5 elements. I named the IDs for the 5 elements individually, "link1" to "link5" and put seperate properties for the 5th element into the ID `#link5`

```css
#banner {
 background-color: grey;
 color:white;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 
}
.link {
 padding: 0px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;  
}
#link5 {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
  }
.selector{ background-color: white;
 color: grey;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="banner">
<div id="link1" class="link"> <div class="selector">Home</div> </div>
<div id="link2" class="link">About</div>
<div id="link3" class="link">Projects</div>
<div id="link4" class="link">About</div>
<div id="link5" class="link">Contact</div>
</div>
</body>
```